# Inconsistent expiry time coming from WSO2. Does anyone knows the reason ?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

We are getting the authentication token from the service which gets it from the WSO2. The expiry time that comes along with the token is not consistent. The expiry time sometimes comes less than 3600. For example: 400 or less etc. For this reason, the user is logging out if the expiry time is less. If it brings consistent expiry time i..e 3600 than the user will always log out after 1 hour which is 3600. but due to the inconsistency the user is facing problem.

Comment: Are you referring to WSO2 IS or WSO2 API Manager?

Comment: As per the documentation that we have, the user credentials are mapped through WSO2 IS to DB users.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `<TimestampSkew>` value in `repository/conf/identity/identity.xml`.

Make it `0` if it's not already.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Will see.

Comment: The issue still persist.

Comment: Is this a single node setup?